# Unable to scan slots with local mode in TwinCAT

Tags: plc, twincat, twincat-ads-.net

I'm currently facing an issue with slot scanning on my PC using TwinCAT. Here's the setup:

- I have a CX2030 PLC with several slots for Beckhoff modules.
- I have another PC connected to one of the CX2030's ports through an RJ45 connection.
- I have set the TwinCAT runtime to local mode as the target system(on my PC).

The problem is that when I try to scan the slots in TwinCAT, it shows no slots detected. However, I can see all the slots when I change the connection by connect through the RJ45 port of an EK1100 module.

I have ensured that my network card supports EtherCAT requirements, and I can see and activate it in the "Show Realtime EtherCAT Compatible Devices" option.

I'm wondering if there's any additional configuration or setup required to enable slot scanning in local mode or on the CX2030. Is there a specific setting or parameter that I might be missing? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never heard of scanning PLC's slave devices by connecting to the PLC's configuration interface while having local runtime, you are basically scanning YOUR network card, which has no slaves. You should choose PLC as the target as the underlying modules are it's slaves.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be connected to the remote target (the PLC) when you scan your devices. When your running in local mode as you're doing now the XAE will try to scan all the devices/EtherCAT masters that are installed on your local computer which is not what you want. Do this:

1. Create an AMS-route to the PLC (CX2030)
2. Put it into config mode
3. Scan I/O

If it doesn't work, make sure that the realtime driver for the NIC that you want your EtherCAT master to run from [is installed](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/ethercatsystem/1036996875.html&id=). If you have your modules installed to the right of the PLC (the E-bus), this should normally have been done. If you use a EK1100 or alike, make sure the NIC that the EK1100 is connected to has the realtime driver installed.

Comment: which is not what you want==> I exactly want this cause i can see my slots as I put the target on cx

Comment: I want to connect my slots through cx2030(without changing my target) same as EK1100  cause It has EtherCATs port

Comment: in short, I just want to use my cx as EK1100 nothing more,(imaging cx is slot with two port of RJ45 that sup EtherCAT and nothing else)

Comment: Your description is to say the least, confusing. Who should control the EK1100? The PLC or your PC?
1. If it's your PLC, do as above.
2. If it's your PC, why do you even involve the PLC? Just cut it out of the equation.

Comment: my pc, the reason is that as I want to link the plc variable on HMI by ads I can't see the variable on the HMI configuration panel so I scan the slots again by my PC and link all variables then change the target and download it on plc and publish HMI respectively.(I do not know why I can't see ads variable even as I build, config and...,  maybe I asked it in another question later)
by the way, I've done it before and it works.

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? What do you want your final device (network) configuration to look like? I am guessing that ultimately you do not want your PC running the PLC code and the final solution should have the CX2030 running the PLC code and being the EtherCat master? If this is the case then you need to do as Jakob says and scan the devices while the target is set up as the CX2030 otherwise it will not find them. If you are having trouble with the HMI side, I would check the HMI is looking for the variables from the right device too (the CX2300).